# Youtube-Data-Api - / Youtube-Transcript-Api - 401 errors trying to retrieve transcripts from my own channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I've always been able to retrieve transcripts with the YouTube Data API if I enter a playlist on my channel. I use these transcripts to write books from my teachings. Recently, I wanted to download all of them so I could embed and store them in a vector database for a knowledge bot. I only retrieved 500 of 2200 and got an "exceed quota" error after running it a few times to troubleshoot and figure out why it wouldn't go beyond 500. That was a week ago. Ever since, I get 401 errors if I try to retrieve any transcripts programmatically. I don't have a support option, I don't believe, but thought someone here might have a tip.

I've tried deleting my keys and generating a new one.  Tried setting it as an environment variable and also hardcoding into script.  Script worked in the past.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using for this task, also, check if you've changed your credentials or those are expired.

Answer (score 0):

Google has quotas on the number of daily calls to the YouTube API. Looks like you hit the limit at 500 for that specific call. Here are the details: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota